# AEM6.2: What could cause NullPointerException in UserPropertiesManagerImpl?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I'm trying to setup some authoring-only users in my local AEM environment, and getting a blank page on login, with this exception in the logs:

```
20.09.2017 13:27:18.351 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1505939238326] GET /projects.html/content/projects HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.adobe.granite.security.user.internal.UserPropertiesManagerImpl.getUserProperties(UserPropertiesManagerImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.shell.collectionpage.collectionpage_jsp.getShowOnboarding(collectionpage_jsp.java:127)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.shell.collectionpage.collectionpage_jsp._jspService(collectionpage_jsp.java:346)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
```

What could be the root cause?

Comment: NPE's are almost always bugs. NPE's are not supposed to be thrown, but handled, possibly via an appropriate exception and a message. Can you share the version of CFP's or fix packages installed? it could be something that was fixed in a fix pack by Adobe, or could be a new bug.

Comment: hi I'm using 6.2, CFP7. I just noticed a `<preferences granite.shell.showonboarding620="false"/>` is present on some users but not others, still investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember running into an issue before where some users didn't have read access to their own `profile` or `preferences` nodes. I suggest double checking the permissions for those users using `/useradmin`.

Comment: I've already moved on and won't be able to try to reproduce the issue now, but in retrospect this is probably exactly what happened. I was playing around with ACL export/import and getting users created through package deploy. At one point I probably did an import of the user node without the proper ACLs, causing this issue.